# where can I find source rpm for amzn repo?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rpm

I need to build a RPM package on my Centos6 EC2 instance, so I think it'll be best to use the "official" specs from amzn. Usually I did that with `yumdownloader --source xxx` but on the EC2 instance it cannot find any.

I checked `/etc/yum.repo.d`, which seems not to have any repo regarding src.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `get_reference_source` python script as described by Shadow Lau, but that needs the package being installed. And you need to run it on EC2 on an Amazon Linux AWS instance.

The script gets the URL to download from alami-source-request.amazonaws.com. Here is how you can use it:

https://alami-source-request.amazonaws.com/cgi-bin/source_request.cgi?instance_id=i&region=eu-west-1&version=2011-08-0&srpm_name=stunnel-4.29-3.6.amzn1.src.rpm

Unfortunately you need to know the exact package name. The version is as it's in the `get_reference_source` script. And it seems there is no validation done on instance_id.

The above URL will return another URL with an access key, where you can download the SRPM for a limited time. After that you have to generate another URL with the above source_request.cgi.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Accessing Source Packages for Reference in 
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.htm

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html 

The 'l' was missing in the html link above :/

Comment: thanks, but when I run the command `get_reference_source -p postfix` , it said I have to install the binary package first. Ironically the reason I have to find the source rpm is that the official postfix package is requiring mysql-libs, which would corrupt with my current mysql installation...